# OleDbException error on Update method

Tags: c#, oledb

Why do I have this error? The error message is: `Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.`

I want to add a record to my database, but it isn't working.
Where is the problem?

The code is:

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter DbDataAdabter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DbDataAdabter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Phone-Book]", connection);

            OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(DbDataAdabter);
            connection.Open();
            DataRow dataRow = myDataset.Tables["salam"].NewRow();

            dataRow[1] = textBox2.Text;
            dataRow[2] = textBox3.Text;
            dataRow[3] = textBox4.Text;
            dataRow[4] = textBox5.Text;

            dataRow.EndEdit();
            myDataset.Tables["salam"].Rows.Add(dataRow);

            DbDataAdabter.Update(myDataset , "salam");

            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to show us the query for `INSERT` statement inside your DataAdapter.

Comment: can you show me your table structure.

Comment: sorry for the delay.
@sajanyamaha: 
dataRow[0] : auto number
dataRow[1] :text
[2]: text
[3]: number
[4]:number

Comment: @KuyaJohn : my code hasn't insert statement. am i have to do that ? my database table have 5 column [number] , [namec] , [gushi] , [tell] , [code] that their data type are in above comment

Answer (score 0):

When using DbDataAdabter.Update() ,you have to be very careful about the datatypes of the table,ie if it is an int in DB then convert it and then insert like:

```
dataRow[1]=(int) dataRow[1]+10;
```

Also check all values have been supplied,here i dont see dataRow[0] supplied anywhere,or is it an auto ID field.